# Popup to display if viewed on mobile

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I have a website that needs to redirect mobile users to a mobile site, however because of the sites being hosted in different places, I can't set the cookie to remember if they've been directed from the mobile site. Therefore there is a continuous loop.

All I want to do now is display a popup if the user is viewing on a mobile, offering them the option to view the website on a mobile or cancel to view the full site.

I know this will be possible in Javascript/jQuery, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Could anybody help me with this please?

Thanks

Comment: Just as an aside, I would advise against 'popups'. They were a bad idea on the desktop and they are even worse on the web. Put a div in the top left of the site to give the mobile link, mobile users will see that. If you put up a popup, how big will it be and where will it go? You have device sizes, resolutions and orientations to worry about. The really correct answer, though, is not to need different sites for different types of user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just just add the pop-up to your HTML, hide it on default and display it if it's a mobile device using CSS.

```
/* hidden on default */
div#popup { display: none; }

/* use a media query to filter small devices */
@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px) {
    /* show the popup */
    div#popup { display: block; }
}
```

This is the best option by far, performance-wise. All modern phones support media-queries, so you won't have issues with that either.

Just add two links asking the user to go to the desktop site or mobile one. If he picks the desktop site, you can leave the popup out using a server-side language, or just remove the popup using javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
// Check for mobile user agent
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
if (mobile) {
    //alert("MOBILE DEVICE DETECTED");              
} else {
    //alert("NO MOBILE DEVICE DETECTED");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the user agent. [Here](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/) you can get detailed information.

Comment: Please summarize the contents of the link; simply posting a link is not helpful.

Comment: User agent needs careful use here; tablet users are likely to want the desktop site, rather than the phone version, as they have the real estate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I have used in the past to detect mobile devices:

```
var ua=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isMobile = 
   screen.width < 500 ||
   ua.indexOf('mobile')!=-1 ||
   ua.indexOf('iphone')!=-1 ||
   ua.indexOf('ipod')!=-1 ||
   ua.indexOf('blackberry')!=-1 ||
   ua.indexOf('windows phone')!=-1 ||
   ua.indexOf('zunewp7')!=-1) && 
   ua.indexOf('tablet')==-1 &&
   ua.indexOf('playbook')==-1 &&
   ua.indexOf('webos')==-1 &&
   ua.indexOf('ipad')==-1;
```

This should detect iPhones, iPods, Blackberries, Windows Phones, ZuneWP7s, most android phones, and many other phones. It will be false for most android tablets, Blackberry Playbooks, WebOS devices, iPads, and many other tablets.