# How to automatically open a popup in mobile browser?

Tags: mobile, popup, autoload

I have implemented a popup that automatically comes up on home page.

This works fine on desktop.

But it doesn't come up on mobile browser.

Is there any specific technique of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you detect that the homepage window is active? I'm assuming your are using something like:

```
if (window.location.href.match('homepage.html') != null){
  your code;
}
```

The answer to this question should be helpful to you:

[Popup to display if viewed on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178609/popup-to-display-if-viewed-on-mobile)

You should implement the logic in css / JavaScript and reference your div (popupWindow element):

```
/* hidden on default */
div#popup { display: none; }

/* use a media query to filter small devices */
@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px) {
/* show the popup */
div#popup { display: block; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ratzschus,

I am doing this


`var webURL = location;`

`if(webURL == 'http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php' || webURL == 'http://www.mywebsite.com/' || webURL == 'http://www.mywebsite.com/#'){`
 `// This is for auto loading of the popup on home page`
 `pop('popDiv');`
`}`



popup is working but is not loading automatically.

Comment: try the following: add window.addEventListener("load", function(event){ your if function}. Plus can you please have a look into your console and see if any error occurs in your script file before your function can be reached? This error might occur on mobile devices only.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a pop-up *window*, the browser on your mobile device may block those by default. In that case, it won't work on the desktop either unless the browser is configured to allow pop-ups.