# Displaying an Alert for All Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I am creating a website which suits to computers (Which use a mouse [Pointer on screen] ). It is not suitable for mobile devices (which have touch screens), because it has some effects like on mouse over/leave. When a user visits the site using a mobile device, it should display a message that 'This Website has a better look with a Computer'.

*Js Part*

```
<script language="Javascript">
window.onload=function {
    alert("Visit this on a Computer for Better View");
}
</script>
```

*HTML Part*

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <p>content</p>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178609/popup-to-display-if-viewed-on-mobile

Comment: @UpendraJoshi Oh! It's title not matches with me. Sorry i should watch it also..

Comment: @UpendraJoshi it is showing a HTML Element in mobile view. But i want to show a javascript alert - alert("Like this")

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This :

```
    <script language="Javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
    var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
    if (mobile) {
        alert("Visit this on a Computer for Better View");              
    } else {

    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have no mobile device now, I check my website by changing broswer width/height. Can i see this alert in this method?

Comment: Thanks! I think it's good! I definitely don't want t to do this, because i made my site with bootstrap. But for hover effects, I wanted this. Thnks Again!

Comment: it will work on mobile devices, and please check my updated answer, i have made some edits

Comment: Can u tell the method to show the message in computers also? as mobile = (/os/os/os) , pc = (/windows/mac/ubuntu/linux) is this method correct?

Comment: you can use navigator.platform.indexOf('Mac') for mac & navigator.platform.indexOf('Win') for windows

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this

```
window.onload=function() {
```

// device detection test with regEx

```
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
|| /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) 
alert("Visit this on a Computer for Better View");
}
```

Comment: question says, alert should display only on mobile devices